# Overriding properties in CSS

Tags: css

```
#iddiv span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 190px;
}
.myclass {
    width:10px;
}
```

Then I have

```
<div id="iddiv">
    <span>hello:</span> 
    <span class="myclass">yeah</span> <br/>
</div>
```

I would like the first `span`'s `width` to be 190px, and second's to be 10px. But both are 190px: why it's not overriding the `width` propoerty?

EDIT: Thanks for your responses. What about unsetting width? I don't want 10px width, just default width as if it was undefined

Comment: Could you post it on jsFiddle so we can take a better look at it? :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because id+selector (#iddiv span) is more specific than a class. Either

```
#iddiv span.myclass
```

or

```
#iddiv .myclass
```

should work for this case.

Learn more about CSS specificity [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) or by Googling it.

Comment: What about unsetting width? I don't want 10px width, just default width as if it was undefined

Answer (score 34):

You could always use the `!important` flag to override:

```
.myclass {
    width: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: This was very useful to me!

Answer (score 5):

CSS applies styles according to the specificity of the selectors

`#iddiv span` is more specific than `myclass`. Changing it to `#iddiv .myclass` should fix the issue for you.

Here's an article that goes more in depth about this : http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

Answer (score 2):

Remember to use the keyword, !important, which functions to overwrite parent rules.

Also you can define your "myclass" in the following way:

```
#iddiv span.myclass {
    width:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because the first style is more specific.

To fix it, make sure you target the second `span` more directly, like this

`#iddiv span.myclass`

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/5fe9A/

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd suggest you properly target your selectors, as others are suggesting.

But when all else fails, you can use [!important](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm).