# How do you directly change style of the source code of react-native-scrollable-tab-view (Reactive Native)?

Tags: javascript, react-native, uitabbar, reactjs, scrollable

I'm trying to access the style property 'bottomBorderColor' to change to 'white' but how can I do so?

The source code is here -- at the bottom of the page in styles:

https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/blob/master/DefaultTabBar.js#L75

Attempted the following but doesn't work:

```
    <ScrollableTabView
      style={{borderBottomColor: 'white'}}
    >
      <Text tabLabel='Tab1'> Testing 1 </Text>
      <Text tabLabel='Tab2'> Testing 2 </Text>
      <Text tabLabel='Tab3'> Testing 3 </Text>
    </ScrollableTabView>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All exposed properties you CAN modify are listed here [props](https://github.com/skv-headless/react-native-scrollable-tab-view/blob/master/DefaultTabBar.js#L13-L22). So the property you are looking could not be passed as a property into component you are using.

**BUT** Why would you want to modify style like that? Having inline styles, or even styling your components through JS is not a good idea. Write a CSS file which would overwrite default styling of the used component instead. This way styling in your program will be easier to understand and to reason about. And more importantly, it will be easier to change or modify, instead of searching all over in the code base for some styling property objects (since styling is usually found in CSS, LESS or SCSS)

Comment: Sorry but could you show an example of CSS file overwriting the default styling? Still in the learning process.

Comment: Checking to see if you've read my previous comment. Please let me know.

Comment: Could you please answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295321/overriding-properties-in-css or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665715/css-not-overwriting-properties-correctly There are plenty examples online you can find. I cannot give you an exact solution to your problem since I have no idea what DOM is being generated and what CSS rules are being applied. But search online on how to overwrite and I'm sure you will find plenty of answers on this question.